# Count the number of ids in a table that match items in another table (Excel)

Tags: excel

I have two sheets in the workbook.  One contains the raw data on sheet 1 (call it Table1) and the other is on sheet 2 (call it table 2)

Table 1

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| ID |   Date    | Status  |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 | 7/22/2020 | WIP     |
|  2 | 11/1/2020 | WIP     |
|  3 | 11/1/2020 | UAT     |
|  4 | 11/1/2020 | Scoping |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

Table 2

```
+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Status  | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr |
+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Scoping |     |     |     |     |
| WIP     |     |     |     |     |
| UAT     |     |     |     |     |
+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I am trying to get a formula that will, based on the date and status, count the ID's for each month.

I tried

`=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[Status]=Table2[@[Status]])*(TEXT(Table1[Date],"mmmyyyy"=AA4&YEAR(TODAY()))))`

But that results in #VALUE

I also tried

`=SUMT(IF(Table1[Status]=[@[Status]],IF((TEXT(Table1[Date],"mmmyyyy"=AA4&YEAR(TODAY()))),),1))`

But that results in #NAME

anyone help with the formula that can do what I am trying to do here?

Comment: Why not just use a pivot table, to be honest.

Comment: The dates in the original table are MM/DD/YYYY and it wasn't working when I tried to do MM/YY, but that might be a better way

Comment: Another option: use COUNTIFS and convert your date headings `Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr` into true dates, then apply formatting to make them appear `Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr`. You can use `>=` and `<=` and `EOMONTH` to dates within each respective month.